# How can I disable the webbrowser message in python?

Tags: python, browser

In my python program, when I send the user to create a gmail account by use of the webbrowser module, python displays:

"Please enter your Gmail username: Created new window in existing browser session."

Is there any way to get rid of "created new window in existing browser session", as it takes up the space where the user types in their Gmail account.

The code for this is:

```
webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount?service=mail')  
gmail_user = raw_input('Please enter your Gmail username: ')
```

**EDIT:** After trying out both of Alex Martelli's suggestions, the code is: http://pastebin.com/3uu9QS4A

**EDIT 2:** I have decided just to tell users to go to the gmail registration page instead of actually sending them there, as that is much simpler to do and results in no (currently-unsolvable-by-me) errors.

Comment: What happens when you switch the order of these two statements?

Comment: I cannot switch them, as this would cause more problems in my code.
If you could take a look at the code http://pastebin.com/GcHL2iYj
maybe you could help more? Thanks.

Comment: Works fine here (MacOSX 10.5). What platforms are you on?  It's supposed to work on all forms of Unix and Windows.  There are other bugs later in your code (two `return`s one after the other will never work of course -- the first one executes, so the second one's never reached) but those aren't germane to your question.

Comment: I'm on debian Linux. And thanks, I'll fix the returns. Because the part of the program that depends on the variables being returned works, I don't even think they're necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As S.Lott hints in a comment, you should probably do the `raw_input` first; however, that, per se, doesn't suppress the message from `webbrowser`, as you ask -- it just postpones it.

To actually *suppress* the message, you can temporarily redirect standard-output or standard-error -- whichever of the two your chosen browser uses to emit that message.  It's probably no use to redirect them at Python level (via `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr`), since your browser is going to be doing its output directly; rather, you can do it at the operating-system level, e.g., for standard output:

```
import os
gmail_user = raw_input('Please enter your Gmail username: ')
savout = os.dup(1)
os.close(1)
os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
try:
   webbrowser.open(whatever)
finally:
   os.dup2(savout, 1)
```

(for standard error instead of standard output, use 2 instead of 1).  This is pretty low-level programming, but since the webbrowser module does not give you "hooks" to control the way in which the browser gets opened, it's pretty much the only choice to (more or less) ensure suppression of that message.

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly, EXCEPT that the part asking for the Gmail username is never displayed.
Maybe if you took a look at the code http://pastebin.com/GcHL2iYj
you would know the answer? Thanks

Comment: @ErikT, in that code there is no `os.dup2(savout, 1)` in the `finally` clause (as I showed in my answer), so that standard output never gets restored -- add it before the `break` line that is now 18.

Comment: After adding that, the program now just ends at that statement instead of going to the next block of code (the gmail username input) like it should.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1352392/1904815) that is relevant here.

You can use

```
webbrowser.get().open('https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount?service=mail')
```

I have xdg-open installed (Linux), which led to a message *START /usr/lib/firefox/firefox* for me when using `webbrowser.open()`.
Using the method above this message is not displayed (and xdg-open is still used).

This supresses output to stdout. It doesn't suppress output to stderr for all setups though. I still have error messages in the terminal.